# How can I add a button into django admin change list view page

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to add a button next to "add" button in list view in model for my model and then create a view function where I will do my stuff and then redirect user back to list view.

I've checked how to overload admin template, but I still dont know, where should I put my view function where I will do my stuff, and how can I register that view into admin urls.

There is also question about security. I would like to have that action inside admin, so if u r not logged in, u cannot use it.

I've found this, but I don't know if it's the right way: http://www.stavros.io/posts/how-to-extend-the-django-admin-site-with-custom/

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> When several applications provide different versions of the same
>   resource (template, static file, management command, translation), the
>   application listed first in INSTALLED_APPS has precedence.
>   - [Django documentation on INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS)

Make sure your app is listed before `'django.contrib.admin'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Create a `change_list.html` template in one of the following directories:

```
# Template applies to all change lists.
myproject/myapp/templates/admin/change_list.html      

# Template applies to change lists in myapp.
myproject/myapp/templates/admin/myapp/change_list.html  

# Template applies to change list in myapp and only to the Foo model.
myproject/myapp/templates/admin/myapp/foo/change_list.html
```

The template should be picked up automatically, but in case it is not on one of paths listed above, you can also point to it via an admin model attribute:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    #... 
    change_list_template = "path/to/change_list.html"
```

You can lookup the contents of the original change_list.html it lives in `path/to/your/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html`. [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919361/how-can-i-add-a-button-into-django-admin-change-list-view-page/#answer-24553887) also shows you how to format the template. Nikolai Saiko shows you how to override the relevant parts using 'extends' and 'super'. Summary:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %} {% load i18n %} 
{% block object-tools-items %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <li>
        <a class="historylink" href="...">My custom admin page</a>
    </li>
{% endblock %}
```

Let's fill `href="..."` with an url. The admin url names are in the namespace 'admin' and can be looked up like this:

```
{% url 'admin:custom_view' %}
```

When you are adding a button to change_form.html you maybe want to pass in the current object id:

```
{% url 'admin:custom_view' original.pk %}
```

Now create a custom view. This can be a regular view (just like other pages on your website) or a custom admin view in admin.py. The get_urls method on a ModelAdmin returns the URLs to be used for that ModelAdmin in the same way as a URLconf. Therefore you can extend them as documented in URL dispatcher:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            url(r'^my_view/$', self.my_view, name="custom_view")
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        # custom view which should return an HttpResponse
        pass

    # In case your template resides in a non-standard location
    change_list_template = "path/to/change_list.html"
```

Read the docs on how to set permissions on a view in ModelAdmin: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

You can protect your view and only give access to users with staff status:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

You might also want to check `request.user.is_active` and handle inactive users.

Update: Take advantage of the framework and customise as little as possible. Many times actions can be a good alternative: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Update 2: I removed a JS example to inject a button client side. If you need it, see [the revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17921946/revisions).

Comment: @allcaps - your solution works great for this requirement of having a button for one ModelAdmin. What about if we one to create another button for a second ModelAdmin? How can we make the href="/path/to/whatever/" dynamic? Thanks

Comment: @hashdava Use a named url e.g. `(r'^my_view/$', self.my_view, name='foo')`. Then override the admin template `change_form.html` by copying it from Django source into the appropriate template dir. Eg: `templates/admin/app_name/model_name/change_form.html`. In the template block `{% block object-tools-items %}` you can put your button: `<li><a href="{% url 'admin:foo' %}">Foo</a></li>`. You can put `change_form.html` also a level higher, then it applies to all change forms in this app. Create folders, templates and url lookups for each model OR use a relative url. Eg: `<a href="foo/">`.

Comment: @allcaps - Thanks for the answer. For my problem I've used change_list.html instead but the solution is the same as you suggested.

Comment: Also now you can call self.admin_site.admin_view(self.my_view) instead of self.my_view to check permissions and mark the view as non-cacheable

Comment: @LucasB seems helpful. Can you point me to the right section in the docs?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

Comment: Thank you, still very helpful.

Answer (score 17):

Here is [another solution](http://patrick.arminio.info/blog/2010/05/additional-admin-views/) , without using of jQuery (like one provided by allcaps). Also this solution provides object's pk with more intuitive way :)

I'll give my source code based on that link (follow link above for more info):

I have an app Products with model Product. This code adds button "Do Evil", which executes ProductAdmin.do_evil_view()

File **products/models.py**:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):   
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/evilUrl/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.do_evil_view))
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def do_evil_view(self, request, pk):
        print('doing evil with', Product.objects.get(pk=int(pk)))
        return redirect('/admin/products/product/%s/' % pk)
```

**self.admin_site.admin_view** is needed to ensure that user was logged as administrator.

And this is template extention of standard Django admin page for changing entry:
File: **{template_dir}/admin/products/product/change_form.html**

In **Django >= 1.8**  (thanks to @jenniwren for this info):

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <li><a class="historylink" href="evilUrl/">{% trans "Do Evil" %}</a></li>
{% endblock %}
```

If your **Django version is lesser than 1.8**, you have to write some more code:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block object-tools %}
{% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
<ul class="object-tools">
    <li><a class="historylink" href="history/">{% trans "History" %}</a></li>
    <li><a class="historylink" href="evilUrl/">{% trans "Do Evil" %}</a></li>
{% if has_absolute_url %}
    <li><a class="viewsitelink" href="../../../r/{{ content_type_id }}/{{ object_id }}/">{% trans "View on site" %}</a></li>
{% endif%}</ul>
{% endif %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Note that django 1.8 now has a block inside the `<ul>` tag: `{% block object-tools-items %}` meaning that you don't have to copy the history and view on site buttons anymore.  Use `{{ block.super }}` and add your own list items before or after it.

Comment: Button links to `/admin/products/product/1/change/evilUrl/` than to `/admin/products/product/1/evilUrl/`. I am using Django 1.9