# Add a button to the Django Admin Change List

Tags: django-forms, django-admin

I want to only use the admin forms as this is a project for myself. I'd like to have a button next to my database entry, that when pressed executes a python function.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a button into django admin change list view page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919361/how-can-i-add-a-button-into-django-admin-change-list-view-page)