# How to rename 'save' button in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am using Django-Grappelli and I want to rename the <kbd>save</kbd> button  to <kbd>sent</kbd> for a particular `model('Event')` registered with admin.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can add a JavaScript wrapper to change the name of the admin <kbd>save</kbd> button.

Check this [other Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919361/how-can-i-add-a-button-into-django-admin-change-list-view-page) for details.

Answer (score 0):

First copy change_list.html from
[path\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\]
then in your django project's outer directory where manage.py is present,
create a folder structure like this [path{**project_name**}\templates\admin\{**app_name**}\{**model_name**}\] and paste the file and make changes,

eg:-Below i have changed value="**{% trans 'Save' %}**" to "**{% trans 'Send' %}**"

change_list.html:-
{% if show_save %}{% endif %}