# Django admin, display actions as buttons

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-admin

In Django admin, there is a drop down list for actions.

What I want to achieve is to get rid of the drop down list, and 'Go' button, and instead, display my actions as buttons.

How can it be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code? What did you tried already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a button into django admin change list view page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919361/how-can-i-add-a-button-into-django-admin-change-list-view-page)

Comment: @wolendranh i didnt try anything, i have been just searching so far, but no solution yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a js file `action_buttons.js` inside your static directory

```
(function ($) {

    function fix_actions() {
        var container = $('div.actions');

        if (container.find('option').length < 10) {
            container.find('label, button').hide();

            var buttons = $('<div></div>')
                .prependTo(container)
                .css('display', 'inline')
                .addClass('class', 'action-buttons');

            container.find('option:gt(0)').each(function () {
                $('<button>')
                    .appendTo(buttons)
                    .attr('name', this.value)
                    .addClass('button')
                    .text(this.text)
                    .click(function () {
                        container.find('select')
                            .find(':selected').attr('selected', '').end()
                            .find('[value=' + this.name + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
                        $('#changelist-form button[name="index"]').click();
                    });
            });
        }
    };

    $(function () {
        fix_actions();
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Copy above code to js file

In you admin.py under admin class add

```
class Media:
    js = ('path/to/action_buttons.js', )
```