# django custom button in admin

Tags: django, button, admin

I am trying to add a custom button in the admin interface. I have overridden search_form.html and added a form field:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
 <input type="submit" value="test" name="test">
</form>
```

In views.py i have a function

```
def test(request):
    ...do stuff here
```

Could someone help me a little on how i can call this function when clicking the 'test' button? MAybe i may be missing something in urls.py but i am not sure. I am using django 1.9.4

Comment: This question possibly duplicate, did you read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919361/how-can-i-add-a-button-into-django-admin-change-list-view-page ?

Comment: Yes, @rischan is right, that's almost a duplicate wtihout being an exact duplicate. That speaks of the listview and this appears to be of the change view but the concept is the same

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!